# Go Benchmark Output Format

Tags: go, go-testing

My function name is `BenchmarkArray1` what does the `-12` represent?

```
BenchmarkArray1-12              1000000000               0.826 ns/op
```

Comment: The concurrency level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is supposed to be interpreted as 12 not -12.

It is the value of `GOMAXPROCS` environment variable. `GOMAXPROCS` is a parameter used by the go scheduler to determine how many OS threads may be actively executing Go code simultaneously.

Its default value is the no. of CPUs in your machine.

`GOMAXPROCS` is actually the value of n in, go's m:n scheduling(m go routines running on n operating system threads)